# VS2015 - Local iOS device build - Cannot find the app installed on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-2015, itunes, apache-cordova

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

**Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked.**

> 2>------ Deploy started: Project: xxx, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
>
> 2>Found iTunes version: 12.4.1.6
>
> 2>Uninstalling app ID:  xxx.
>
> 2>Successfully installed .ipa file:  D:_Rina Files\Resources\Multiservice - Smart Apps\WorkingDirectories\smartapps\xxx\xxx\bin\iOS\Debug\SmartApp.ipa.
>
> 2>Starting idevicedebugserverproxy.exe at port 3000.
>
> 2>Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked.
>
> 2>Starting ios_webkit_debug_proxy.exe at port 9221.
>
> 2>Deployment failed.
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I can successfully debug/deploy our app on a device connected to the Mac but for a device connected to Windows, I am having the said problem. The device is connected, awake, and unlocked. iTunes can detect the device in my Windows.

Unfortunately, this [link](http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/) did not help me as my XCode is already in version 7.3.1.
Some also suggested increasing the timeout settings in the RemoteBuild.config. Someone else might have done it already (as it has already been set to 60000 when I checked) and still no luck.

This information might help:

1. XCode ver 7.3.1
2. iTunes ver 12.4.1.6
3. iPad Mini (Local Device) ver 9.3.2
4. XCode Deployment Target is set to 9.2. (There is no 9.3 in the list.)
5. RemoteBuild.config in Mac has been edited. appLaunchStepTimeout and emulatorLaunchTimeout have been set to 60000
6. I tried to install the app myself by getting the generated IPA and dragging it in iTunes App pane. Then I selected the connected device, clicked the Apps button, then clicked Install then Apply. I can see the icon in the device and it states "Waiting" to "Loading" to "Installing". Once it finishes installing, the icon disappears.

I felt the last information might be the key to resolving this information.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction in resolving this issue.

Comment: Could you please try [You try to run your app on a device that is connected to your Windows computer but the project can't find it](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#timeout).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT - Good day! I'm very sorry for the late response as I was only able to get back to this task now.
Unfortunately, stopping the two processes mentioned (ios-webkit-debug-proxy.exe and idevicedebugserverproxy.exe) did not work for me.